# Create tabs with merge area

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-material

How can I create Tabs with Angular-Material look like this picture below :
(I don't know how to describe it in English so I call it is "merges tab" )

[image: MyImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stab at it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXBVRd). I think it can be improved.

[image]

Markup

Some description

Tab One
        
      
      
        
          Tab Two
        
      
      
        
          Tab Three
        
      
      
        
          Tab Four

CSS

```
#myTabs {
  margin-top: -40px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#myTabs md-tab-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#myTabs md-tabs-canvas, 
#myTabs md-pagination-wrapper {
  height: 100px
}

#myTabs .md-tab {
  line-height: 80px
}

#tabsDescription {
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabsDescription {
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabsDescription p {
  margin: 5px -60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```